# Doubts on definition of spin structure

Tags: differential-geometry, principal-bundles, spin-geometry

In Friedrich's book "Dirac operators in Riemannian geometry" there is this definition for spin structure.

Let $X$ be a CW-complex and $(Q, \pi, X, SO(n))$ a $SO(n)$-principal bundle on $X$. A spin structure on $Q$ is a pair $(P, \Lambda)$ such that

- $P$ is a $Spin(n)$ principal bundle on X,
- $\Lambda: P \rightarrow Q$ is a 2-fold covering for which the following diagram commutes

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
P \times Spin(n) @>>> P\\
@VVV @VVV\\
Q \times SO(n) @>>> Q
\end{CD}

where $\Lambda \times \lambda : P \times Spin(n) \rightarrow Q \times SO(n)$ and $\lambda: Spin(n) \rightarrow SO(n)$ is the standard covering map.

But everywhere else I find a different definition of spin structure, starting from an oriented vector bundle $E \rightarrow X$ and defining a spin structure on the frame bundle $P_{SO}(E)$ with the same properties described above.

Are these two definitions equivalent? I think yes, since to a $SO(n)$-principal bundle I can associate an oriented vector bundle, but I'm not sure if I'm missing something. Also why do we want X to be a CW-complex?